# Angular project migration 5 to 6 - Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I'm migrating my angular project from version 5 to 6 following the steps mentioned here [angular migration steps](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=5.2-6.0).

I did all steps but when i run the command ng serve, i got the error **Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling**

Here the result of the command **ng -v**
[image]

I've tried all suggested solutions mentioned in stackoverflow to avoid duplications, but none of them worked for me.

Thanks